what are pivot rod dimension for kingston brass KS3600 drain assembly?
pivot rod end that moves the stopper is rotted away.  There are several replacement kits but I am having trouble figuring out dimensions of the pivot rod:  ball diameter, rod diameter and length (am unable to bend far enough to measure)

You can get a whole new pop-up drain kit for under $20 then you don't have to match repair parts.  If the old one has begun rotting away it wouldn't be a bad idea to replace the whole kit.  The faucet model should be irrelevant.  Usually.  Two rods attached by a universal metal clip.

That's a dimension that is most difficult to find and as a result it is never looked for. Instead most of us use the "try it and see" method.  This is not something that needs rocket science.
